# When is the environment.rb file loaded in a rails 3 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I dont' see any reference to my environment.rb file in my rails 3 app, I must be not looking at the right place.

Is it called differenlty now, I thought it was in /public/dispatch.rb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in `config.ru`. This is a [Rack-up file](https://github.com/rack/rack/wiki/%28Tutorial%29-Rackup-HowTo), that any Rack complient server will load when starting the app. It contains something like this:

```
require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment',  __FILE__)
run YourApp::Application
```

The first line loads your environment.
The second line tells the Rack server that your application is the Rack application to load.

Comment: so prior to rails 3 wasn't rack?